# Как скомпилировать программу? То filesystem не видит, то sqlite не линкует

Tags: c++, linux, сборка, линковка

Столкнулся с проблемой:

```
kali ~ # cat main.cpp
...
#include <filesystem>
#include <sqlite3.h>
namespace file = std::filesystem;
...
```

```
kali ~ # ls /usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/g++ -> g++-11
kali ~ # ls /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -> g++-11
kali ~ # g++ main.cpp -lsqlite3 -o main
# OK
kali ~ # g++ main.cpp -lsqlite3 -o main -static
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/libstdc++.a(locale_init.o): in function `std::locale::locale()':
(.text._ZNSt6localeC2Ev+0x54): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
...
kali ~ # apt list | grep musl
musl [installed]
musl-dev [installed]
musl-tools [installed]
kali ~ # g++-10 main.cpp -o main -lsqlite3 -static -lstdc++-17
main.cpp:12:23: error: ‘filesystem’ is not a namespace-name
   12 | namespace file = std::filesystem;
kali ~ # nano main.cpp
kali ~ # g++-10 main.cpp -o main -lsqlite3 -static -lstdc++-17
main.cpp:12:23: error: ‘std::fs’ has not been declared                                 12 | namespace file = std::fs::filesystem;
```

Я пробовал и менять namespace file, и экспериментировать с компиляторами - без толку! Без `-static` g++-то спокойно компилирует, только вот мне принципиально надо `-static`, musl благо уже стоит. Есть и libsqlite3.a, и libc.a, и libstdc++.a.

Comment: Судя по самой первой ошибке, не хватает `-pthread`. Значит `g++ main.cpp -lsqlite3 -o main -static -pthread`?

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a(os_unix.o): in function `unixDlClose':                                                       (.text+0x914): undefined reference to `dlclose'                                           /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a(os_unix.o): in function `unixDlSym':
(.text+0x928): undefined reference to `dlsym'                                             /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.a(os_unix.o): in function...

Comment: не хочет линковать

Comment: Погуглите "undefined reference to dlsym". Вроде `-ldl` нужен.

Comment: помогло. Выскочило предупреждение про dlopen, но я проверил файл в Android хосте - хорошо работает, segfault не ловлю, strace тоже пишет, что все норм.